# How to use an index to recall a label of a dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

maybe it's a trivial question but I cant find an answer to this problem:
I have a dataframe with these columns:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df.columns
Index(['label', 'num.feature 1', 'num.feature 2', 'num.feature 3',
   'num.feature 4', 'num.feature 5',...,'num.feature 30'],
  dtype='object')
```

I would like to find a way to access the columns using an index variable i in the name of the column

```
for i in range(30):
    df['num.feature **i**'].hist(bins=90,range=(0,0.4))
```

For example to print the various histograms for each columns. 
Are there better ways to do it? thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways:

**Method 1** Extract your features of interest beforehand, and iterate through those. IMO, this is cleaner, as if you're missing a feature name, it will still work (*i.e.* if you don't have for example `num.feature 6`)

```
features = [i for i in df.columns if i.startswith('num.feature')]

for feature in features:
    plt.hist(df[feature], bins=90, range=(0,0.4))
```

**Method 2** Create the relevant feature names on the fly (you'll run into trouble if you're missing a feature name)

```
for i in range(1,31):
    plt.hist(df['num.feature '+str(i)])
```

Comment: you can slice with `df.loc[:, cf.columns.str.startswith('num.feature')]`

Comment: @piRSquared, yeah, that's much nicer!

Comment: Thank you very much for the exhaustiv answer! how can I incorporate the comment of @piRSquared in the code? just in the first line when i create features?

Answer (score 1):

You are pretty much there. just need to add format.

```
for i in range(30):
    df['num.feature {}'.format(i)].hist(bins=90,range=(0,0.4))
```

Should be good now.

Comment: And with Python 3.6+ `df[f'num.feature {i}']`

Answer (score 1):

### `pandas.DataFrame.filter`

```
df.filter(regex='^num.feature \d+$').hist()
```

Comment: I obtain exactly the kind of histrograms that I want: every plot in a different figure but It's very caothic the result